# Use getActivity() as a Context or as an Activity

Tags: android, android-context

I have a question concerning the use of `getActivity()`.

If I have for example these 2 different uses:

Here I just use `getActivity()` to provide a `Context`:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

And here I use it to get assets:

```
getActivity().getAssets();
```

My question is, is there any difference between those 2 lines if the `Activity` has not been added to the `Fragment` yet?

Is it possible to get a null pointer if `getActivity()` is only used as a `Context`?

I hope my question is clear...

**UPDATE**: For the ones down voting, at least please explain why...

Thank you

Comment: when you try use reference of activity in fragment then we always get this reference using getActivity() so it's never return null.

Comment: Hmm I don't see what you mean, I had to handle several random null pointers on `getActivity()` in fragments.

Comment: Read up on [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with this solution for my `Fragments`, and I did not get any error since:

I will actually get the context for the `Fragment` as soon as possible, in the method `onAttach()`:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    mContext = activity;
}
```

Thanks to this, I can use the `Activity`'s context anywhere in the class.

For the cases where I need to get elements from the `Activity` itself, I will do it in the method `onActivityCreated()` that guarantees that the `Activity` will be fully initialized.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the device screen size
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    (...)
}
```